# Add Fade-in effect to imageview image [Android]

Tags: java, android

Guys I need help to understand, how to add some animation to static imageview. My project contains this:

layout/drawer_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/launcher_icon"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
        android:flipInterval="3000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="245dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/vert_loading" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

anim/fadein.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="2000"/>
```

anim/fadeout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

The question is: How to fadein and fadeout image automaticaly:

```
 android:src="@drawable/vert_loading"
```

Add something to MainActiviti.java?

Answer (score 0):

In you java code you need to `startAnimation` & to repeat one after another you can listen using `setAnimationListener`. When `onAnimationEnd` is called for one you can call another `startAnimation`.

Following is the example for your use case:

```
//find imageview
        ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);

        // get Animation objcets
        Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
        Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);

        //set the initial animation
        image.startAnimation(fadeIn);

        //set fadeIn listener
        fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //when fadeIn ends start the fadeout
                image.startAnimation(fadeOut);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        //set fadeout listener
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //when fadeOut ends start the fadeIn
                image.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok but I got:

error: method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity
    private void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: @JarosławKról Just make sure you don't have two `onCreate` . if you already have that delete the empty method.

Comment: Yes I have one oncreate:
Here is my MainActivity.java

https://file.io/k8jNYl2s36u2
Would You please take a look at this?

Comment: @JarosławKról I clicked on the link. it tells me "The file you requested has been deleted".

Comment: @JarosławKról I went through your code & I think you just need to put the code i gave you in your `onCreate` where you're doing `Config.USE_DRAWER` i think. You've to find the drawer icon image view there & replace it in my given code.  I've updated the code

Comment: @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //when fadeIn ends start the fadeout
                image.startAnimation(fadeOut);
            }


GOT THIS:

error: local variable image is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                image.startAnimation(fadeOut);